# AAPT: error: resource android:attr/android:progressBarStyleSmall not found

Tags: android, androidx, payumoney

C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\9f39f95ecc02dcabb161a6205cd680b4\jetified-magicretry-1.0.6\res\layout-v11\magicretry_fragment.xml:121: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/android:progressBarStyleSmall not found.

I am using PayuMoney payment gateway SDK
I am getting this error after migrating to AndroidX.

Please help me to solve this issue.

build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sk.sk"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 23
        versionName "2.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'app/', 'android_assets', 'android_asset'] }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/PGSDK_v1.0.1.jar')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.25.9'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'
    implementation 'ch.acra:acra:4.6.1'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper:urlimageviewhelper:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.2.+'
    implementation 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.3@aar'
    implementation files('libs/core-2.1.jar')
    implementation project(':linkedin-sdk')
    implementation 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.5.0'
    //implementation 'com.payumoney.core:payumoney-sdk:7.5.0'
    //implementation project(':sdkui')
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Until they solve the issue with the library

Create a file in res/layout-v11/magicretry_fragment.xml

Put the following code in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dots="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/magic_retry_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/retry_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple_drawable"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh_black_36dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/trusticon"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/four"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/cb_textColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/twelveScaled"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/four"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/four"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Powered by"
                android:textColor="@color/cb_textColor"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"

                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/four"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/logo_payu"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/four"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/cb_textColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/twelveScaled"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/error_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="@string/MR_Error_text"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/error_title2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="@string/MR_Tap_retry_text"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <!-- Button
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="@string/b_cancel"
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:background="@drawable/approve_otp_button"
            style="@style/approve_otp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/eight"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/eight"
            android:textStyle="bold"/ -->


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/waiting_dots_parent"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/magic_reload_progress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Worked for me. Atleast this made the project to run. But since this is an error from the payumoney sdk, there is pretty much nothing we can do unless they change their code.

Comment: I am not able to change it how can we change ?!

Comment: @chiragpatel you've to create a new file in the folder mentioned above

Comment: When i try to build using Android Studio 3.5.1 i got following error
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/apple/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/f796dfe5a44f2d9e2acc296030be076d/jetified-magicretry-1.0.6/res/layout-v11/magicretry_fragment.xml","position":{"startLine":120}}],"original":"/Users/apple/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/f796dfe5a44f2d9e2acc296030be076d/jetified-magicretry-1.0.6/res/layout-v11/magicretry_fragment.xml:121: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/android:progressBarStyleSmall not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}

Answer (score 15):

After wasting 3 hours, finally updating to **1.6.0** solved mine..

```
implementation 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.6.0'
```

Comment: yes they handle in 1.6.0 version this fix thank you @SRB

Answer (score 8):

Seems it's a problem in their SDK at the moment. The best solution would be to write to their support and ask to fix ASAP

```
<ProgressBar
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/magic_reload_progress"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            style="?android:attr/android:progressBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

to

```
<ProgressBar
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/magic_reload_progress"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

in file `jetified-magicretry-1.0.6/res/layout-v11/magicretry_fragment.xml`

Comment: jetified-magicretry-1.0.6/res/layout-v11/magicretry_fragment.xml this is payumoney library file we can not change it

Comment: That's why I wrote ask a support

Comment: Much helpful. Facing this during Android-X migration. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try their latest SDK version which is 1.5.0 at the moment

Comment: I am already using latest version which is implementation 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.5.0'

Comment: @sandeepkolhal clear project doesn't help? Have you migrated project to AndroidX?

Comment: Yes have done with clear project, rebuild project and invalidate cache restart.
And yes I am getting this issue after migrating to androidx

Comment: @sandeepkolhal could you please share your build gradle file

Comment: Please check my gradle file, I have edited in question.

Answer (score 1):

Under gradle file(Module:app) update the below dependency to latest:

implementation  'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.6.0'

This will help as they have resolved the issue in new SDK.