# How to deal with and error like "resource android:attr/android:progressBarStyleSmall not found" in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Everything was fine and working perfect until I got an error in my Xamarin project like this:

C:\Users\user\source\repos\WeatherApp\WeatherApp\WeatherApp.Android\obj\Debug\110\lp\1\jl\res\layout\activitysmallindicator.xml:1: error: resource android:attr/android:progressBarStyleSmall not found. "android:progressBarStyleSmall not found".

I found an answer to that issue in the previous questions who said to create a file myself and copy-paste his written codes in that file but it is no luck! It is still not working!

Comment: When searching for solutions always check the date of the solution.  In this case two years ago the library had a bug that was fixed by using newer version of library.  Update library.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57588753/aapt-error-resource-androidattr-androidprogressbarstylesmall-not-found

Comment: Thanks for your help but I think I clearly stated that it was no help in my question! You should pay more attention to the question @jdweng !

Comment: I do not think you comments is appropriate.  I certainly did read your question and found somebody who had the same issue two years ago.  I do not know when you updated the library and after updating forgot to do a clean build.   We do not know what you changed to cause the error.  When posting it is always important to know what changed.  An error just doesn't start happening by itself in a working project.  My answer was appropriate based on the information you provided.

Answer (score 1):

I think I could deal with this issue myself!
The problem was when I corrected
?style= android:attr/android:progressBarStyleSmall  to  ?style=android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall ,  I **rebuilt** the solution which triggered my xml file to rewrite it in its own wrong way again. I needed just **Build** this solution so the VS could save corrected one and work again.